# Add visual studio project to AOT var layer in Dynamics AX

Tags: visual-studio, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I would like to add project to AOT in Dynamics AX. When I open AX the added project is in **usr** layer, but I would like to have it in **var** layer. What should I change in Visual Studio settings?

[image]

In application explorer is USR model how can I change it to var?

Answer (score 3):

To open a specific configuration, you can use the /AxConfig switch with a parameter of either a configuration name or the path and file name of a configuration file (.axc file). If your configuration name or configuration file name contains spaces, be sure to enclose the parameter in quotes. If no parameter is specified, then the default configuration is used.

Please check the following link for details
[How to: Open Visual Studio with a Specific Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg889291.aspx).
And of course you need VAR layer license code for this.